# Let $A,B, C,A',B'$ be an abelian groups. Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ be group homomorphisms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Let $A,B, C,A',B'$ be an abelian groups.
Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ be group homomorphisms.

Suppose $A'\cong A$, $B'\cong B$ and $C\cong C'$ as abelian groups and $imf\subset kerg$.

Let $f':A'\to B'$ and $g':B'\to C'$ be induced map.
($f'$ is a composition map $ A'\cong A\to B\cong B'$, and the same for $g'$ )

Then, How can we say there is an isomorphism between $kerf/imf \cong kerf'/img'$ ?

If both $kerf$ and $img$ is finite, it is clear $kerf/imf$ and $kerf'/img'$ has the same order, but I'm stuck with constructing isomorphism between them.

Comment: "Then, How can we say there is an isomorphism between $kerf/imf \cong kerf′/img′$". Here, are you asking for isomorphisms between $ker f$ and $ker f'$ and $im g$ and $im g'$? I think there's a typo here, and also the way you've written this makes it look like you are taking quotients, which is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preliminary fact.**

Consider a commutative square of abelian groups as below, where the horizontal homomorphisms are isomorphisms: $\require{AMScd}$
$$\begin{CD}
M@>\sim>>M'\\
@V\alpha VV @V\beta VV\\
N@>\sim>> N'
\end{CD}$$

1. The unique homomorphism $\operatorname{ker}\alpha\to\operatorname{ker}\beta$ which makes the following square commutative is an isomorphism:
   $$\begin{CD}
   \operatorname{ker}\alpha@>>>\operatorname{ker}\beta\\
   @VVV @VVV\\
   M@>\sim>> M'
   \end{CD}$$
2. The unique homomorphism $N/\operatorname{im}\alpha\to N'/\operatorname{im}\beta$ which makes the following square commutative is an isomorphism:
   $$\begin{CD}
   N@>\sim>>N'\\
   @VVV @VVV\\
   N/\operatorname{im}\alpha@>>> N'/\operatorname{im}\beta
   \end{CD}$$

**Answer.**

In your problem, you obtain an isomorphism $h:\operatorname{ker}g\to\operatorname{ker}g'$, using point (1) on the following square: $$\begin{CD}
B@>\sim>>B'\\
@Vg VV @Vg' VV\\
C@>\sim>> C'
\end{CD}$$ Since $\operatorname{im}f\subset\operatorname{ker}g$ and $\operatorname{im}f'\subset\operatorname{ker}g'$, you get the following square:$$\begin{CD}
A@>\sim>>A'\\
@Vf VV @Vf' VV\\
\operatorname{ker}g@>h>> \operatorname{ker}g'
\end{CD}$$
Applying point (2) to the latter square gives the isomorphism you're looking for.

Comment: But when $M=2\Bbb{Z}$, $M'=\Bbb{Z}$, $N=\Bbb{Z}$ and $N'=\Bbb{Z}$ and $α,β$ are both  inclusions, I think $N/imα$ and $N'/imβ$ is not isomorphic.

Comment: Oh, but this does not make the square diagram commutative.